# Share the same map on all android clients

Tags: java, android, node.js, google-maps, firebase

I'm working on a native android app that's uses google maps to shows all the people connected on the app with real time tracking.

but the problem is  too much data to handle on the client phone 10,0000+ moving markers, so i was wondring if there is a way to handle and set the markers from my back end and share the same map on all the connected devices.

Ps: i'm using node js for backend and firebase to store client positions

Comment: If it is acceptable to limit based on geographical area then consider Geofire using lat-lng boundaries of screen with a maximum.  The issue with clustering it is implied that you'll still be fetching all the markers whether or not they are visible as a result of clustering.

Answer (score 1):

i will rather suggest other options:

- first try to show only a small number of markers in one screen (max
  50 markers), this way you can make sure that you all the phone can
  use your application without lagging or user frustration.
- Depending on zoom level you can cluster markers of a map, this way
  the map can show all the markers without any issue.

refer to this google developer documentation to implement Clustering

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering